# Combining two nested lists R

Tags: r, list, nested

I have a variable that is hierarchically encoded in a data frame. Like so:

```
df$variable
[1] "62010" "79110" "69202" "96040" "90010" "59200" ...
```

Now I would like to change this into a list. Like so:

```
 $ :List of 2
 ..$ : chr "62"
 ..$ :List of 2
 .. ..$ : chr "620"
 .. ..$ : List of 2
 .. .. ..$ : chr "6201"
 .. .. ..$ : List of 1
 .. .. .. ..$ : chr "62010"
```

I've managed to create two two-leveled nested lists, by:

```
l1 <- lapply(unique(df$variable)), list)
l2 <- unique(lapply(l1, function(x) substr(x, 1,2)))
l3 <- unique(lapply(l1, function(x) substr(x, 1,3)))
l4 <- unique(lapply(l1, function(x) substr(x, 1,4)))
l5 <- unique(lapply(l1, function(x) substr(x, 1,5)))

l23 <- mapply(list, l2, lapply(l2, function(x) l3[substr(l3,1,2) == x]), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
l45 <- mapply(list, l4, lapply(l4, function(x) l5[substr(l5,1,4) == x]), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

This has generated the following:

```
 str(l23)
 $ :List of 2
 ..$ : chr "62"
 ..$ :List of 1
 .. ..$ : chr "620"
```

and

```
str(l45)
$ :List of 2
..$ : chr "6201"
..$ :List of 1
.. ..$ : chr "62010"
```

Any insight into how to combine these two lists? Or perhaps how to go about it in an all different way?

**EDIT**
Added dput:

```
dput(l1)
list(list("62010"), list("79110"), list("69202"), list("96040"), 
list("90010"), list("59200"), list("43320"), list("90020"), 
list("46220"), list("90030"), list("70220"), list("86909"), 
list("58110"), list("82990"), list("45110"), list("45201"), 
list("68203"), list("46720"), list("46510"), list("95290"), 
list("85510"), list("68204"), list("41200"), list("74900"), 
list("59120"), list("13921"), list("96090"), list("74102"), 
list("96022"), list("70210"))

dput(l23)
list(list("62", list("620")), list("79", list("791", "799")), 
list("69", list("692", "691")), list("96", list("960")), 
list("90", list("900")), list("59", list("592", "591")), 
list("43", list("433", "432", "439", "431")), list("46", 
    list("462", "467", "465", "463", "464", "461", "466")), 
list("70", list("702")), list("86", list("869", "862")), 
list("58", list("581", "582")), list("82", list("829", "821", 
    "822", "823")), list("45", list("451", "452", "453")), 
list("68", list("682", "683")), list("95", list("952")), 
list("85", list("855", "856", "851", "854", "853")), list(
    "41", list("412", "411")), list("74", list("749", "741", 
    "742", "743")), list("13", list("139")), list("47", list(
    "479", "475", "472", "476", "477", "471", "474")), list(
    "88", list("889", "881")), list("73", list("731")), list(
    "71", list("711", "712")), list("66", list("661")), list(
    "49", list("494", "493")), list("32", list("329", "324", 
    "325")), list("63", list("631")), list("10", list("107", 
    "108")), list("93", list("931", "932")), list("81", list(
    "812", "813")))

dput(l45)
list(list("6201", list("62010")), list("7911", list("79110")), 
list("6920", list("69202", "69201")), list("9604", list("96040")), 
list("9001", list("90010")), list("5920", list("59200")), 
list("4332", list("43320")), list("9002", list("90020")), 
list("4622", list("46220")), list("9003", list("90030")), 
list("7022", list("70220")), list("8690", list("86909", "86905", 
    "86901")), list("5811", list("58110")), list("8299", 
    list("82990")), list("4511", list("45110")), list("4520", 
    list("45201", "45203")), list("6820", list("68203", "68204", 
    "68201", "68202", "68209")), list("4672", list("46720")), 
list("4651", list("46510")), list("9529", list("95290")), 
list("8551", list("85510")), list("4120", list("41200")), 
list("7490", list("74900")), list("5912", list("59120")), 
list("1392", list("13921")), list("9609", list("96090")), 
list("7410", list("74102", "74101", "74103")), list("9602", 
    list("96022", "96021")), list("7021", list("70210")), 
list("4791", list("47919", "47912", "47911", "47916", "47914")))
```

This is my first question so please excuse me if I've failed to clarify anything.

**EDIT**
So to clarify the number roots are not unique, several nodes will share a parent. Take "90010" and "90020" for example.They should both be organized within the parent list of "90" as well as the child-list of "900", but then split into "9001" and "9002". I've added a larger dput to exemplify. Unfortunately the previous and shorter dput did not indicate that this could happen. My apologies.

Comment: Updated, hope I did that right?

Comment: Sorry about that, updated with dput(head(x)) this time, will that work?

Comment: Is your `l1` actually what you want to use as input, or do you want input in the form of `df$variable` as at the top of the question? The first is a list of lists, the second looks to be a character vector

Comment: @CalumYou , Yes, l1 is what I want to use as input. Perhaps a bit confusing, should I remove `df$variable`? From the question I mean

Comment: @fmfrisch Any reason to not use `df$variable` directly? It is generally advisable to work with vectors in R.

Comment: @Novice `df$variable` doesn't quite look like portrayed here, the strings have been trimmed and gsub'ed, and because I wanted it to be a list in the end I transformed it into a list while gsubbing and trimming. That isn't of course necessary, but I felt like it narrowed the question in a useful way.

Comment: @fmfrisch I understand, thank you for clarifying. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way that I think gives what you want. Not knowing how long each string could be, I made it recursive. Basically `to_sublist` takes a `string_list`, i.e. one of the elements of `l1` that look like `list("62010)`, and starts making the hierarchy from the bottom. If the string is longer than 2 it drops a character and puts it one level up, then calls itself to continue the process. Then we can `lapply` it to `l1` and get the desired result.

```r
l1 <- list(list("62010"), list("79110"), list("69202"), list("96040"), list("90010"), list("59200"))

to_sublist <- function(string_list){
  string <- string_list[[1]]

  if (nchar(string) == 2){
    return(string_list)
  } else {
    substring <- substr(string, 1, nchar(string) - 1)
    sublist <- list(substring, string_list)
    return(to_sublist(sublist))
  }
}

l_out <- lapply(l1, to_sublist)
str(l_out[1:2])
#> List of 2
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "62"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "620"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "6201"
#>   .. .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "62010"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "79"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "791"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "7911"
#>   .. .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "79110"
```

Created on 2018-06-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

------- EXPLORATION --------

```r
eg1 <- list(
  list("12345"),
  list("12340"),
  list("12300"),
  list("12000"),
  list("10000")
  )
eg2 <- list(
  list("1234", list("12345", "12340")),
  list("1230", list("12300")),
  list("1200", list("12000")),
  list("1000", list("10000"))
  )
eg3a <- list(
  list("123", list("1234", list("12345", "12340"), "1230", list("12300"))),
  list("120", list("1200", list("12000"))),
  list("100", list("1000", list("10000")))
  )
eg3b <- list(
  list("123", list("1234", "1230", list("12345", "12340", "12300"))),
  list("120", list("1200", list("12000"))),
  list("100", list("1000", list("10000")))
)
str(eg1)
#> List of 5
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ : chr "12345"
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ : chr "12340"
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ : chr "12300"
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ : chr "12000"
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ : chr "10000"
str(eg2)
#> List of 4
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "1234"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "12345"
#>   .. ..$ : chr "12340"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "1230"
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : chr "12300"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "1200"
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : chr "12000"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "1000"
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : chr "10000"
str(eg3a)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "123"
#>   ..$ :List of 4
#>   .. ..$ : chr "1234"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "12345"
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "12340"
#>   .. ..$ : chr "1230"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "12300"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "120"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "1200"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "12000"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "100"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "1000"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "10000"
str(eg3b)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "123"
#>   ..$ :List of 3
#>   .. ..$ : chr "1234"
#>   .. ..$ : chr "1230"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "12345"
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "12340"
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "12300"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "120"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "1200"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "12000"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "100"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "1000"
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "10000"
```

Created on 2018-06-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't keep the structure intact. I'm afraid the dput is somewhat unclear in this regard due to my shortening. Lets take your output `str(l_out[2:2])` as an example. It goes `list("79", list("791", list("7911", list("79110"))))`. Compare that to my output of l23 `list(list("79", list("791", "799")))`. Meaning there are an uneven distributed amount of "neighbors" that should reside on the same level. The desired output would be `list("79", list("791", "799", list("7911", list("79110"))))`

Comment: Sorry, in that case can you expand on what determines what should be on what level? The example seems to just suggest that you want one fewer character as you go up a level. Where does the `"799"` come from when the second element of `l1` is `list("79110")`?

Comment: This is a categorical variable hierarchically encoded like a structure of a tree. so "79" is a parent to "799" and "791". The latter is itself a parent to "7911" that in turn is a parent to "79110". Nchar does define level, but there might be more than one node on each level. Your solution creates duplicate parents for each sibling node. So it creates a structure with two "79" parents, one for "791" and one for "799". But the desired output would be for them to share the same parent. I should add that all variables in l1 has `nchar=5` so they all have the same levels, but they can share parent

Comment: can you add some example `l1`  for which these cases arise then? There is currently no 5-char string that starts "799". I also begin to question if this is the best way to organise this data...

Comment: `list(list("62010"), list("79110"), list("69202"), list("96040"), 
    list("90010"), list("59200"), list("43320"), list("90020"), 
    list("46220"), list("90030"), list("70220"), list("86909"), 
    list("58110"), list("82990"), list("45110"), list("45201"), 
    list("68203"), list("46720"), list("46510"), list("95290"), 
    list("85510"), list("68204"), list("41200"), list("74900"), 
    list("59120"), list("13921"), list("96090"), list("74102"), 
    list("96022"), list("70210"))` Here's a more larger head. With several examples of different members sharing parents.

Comment: Ok, i think there is another point of confusion, since your `l23` and `l45`do not extend far enough to cover this. I edited answer to illustrate: should it be `eg3a` or `eg3b` at the third stage, or something else? I also strongly would recommend just storing this in a dataframe, it would be a lot simpler and less error prone I think

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time, I'm sorry my question has been so unclear. This is formatting preparation for a json export for further work in javascript. That's the reason for the unusual formatting. `eg3a` is my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are a few different ways you can go about solving your problem. As a matter of fact, it seems to be closely related to [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array), but in your case it seems to be a prefix array and does not include either the empty ('$') or the singleton (in your case, the first character).

Here is my solution proposal using only `base` R:

```
pref_list <- function(str) {
    pl <- function(str, l, n) {
        if (n == 2)
            return(list(substr(str, 1, n), l))
        pl(str, list(substr(str, 1, n), l), n - 1)
    }
    pl(str, list(str), nchar(str) - 1)
}
```

Applying to the column in your data:

```
res <- lapply(df$variable, pref_list)
str(res[[1]])
#>List of 2
#> $ : chr "62"
#> $ :List of 2
#>  ..$ : chr "620"
#>  ..$ :List of 2
#>  .. ..$ : chr "6201"
#>  .. ..$ :List of 1
#>  .. .. ..$ : chr "62010"
```

**Edit**: I have just read in the comments that you actually want to use `l1` as input. I would advise using `df$variable` directly, but here is a way to use `l1` if you wish:

```
res <- lapply(unlist(l1), pref_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answer. Unfortunately this runs into the same issue as the previous answer as it creates duplicate parent structures. i.e "90010" and "90020" will be sorted into two separate parent structures. I've updated my question, I'm sorry that it was a bit unclear.

Comment: @fmfrisch I see, that changes things. In any case, what you are trying to do is a prefix tree. I suggest looking at [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) algorithms such as [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm).